# Matlab - longest long axis of the minimum ellipse

Tags: matlab, axis, long-integer, ellipse

I need to find the longest long axis of the minimum ellipse of the components generated using CCL (to use as a threshold). I used matlab for generating connected components (bwlabel method).

I am new to matlab and any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [REGIONPROPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html#bqkf8jb).

```
stats = regionprops(ccl,'MajorAxisLength');
majAx = cat(1, stats.MajorAxisLength);

%# find the longest long axis, and the 
%# index into connComp.PixelIdxList
%# of the object with the longest long axis
[longestLongAxis,idxOfLongFeature] = max(majAx);
```